# Receiving value from Dictionary in another class in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a GameLoader to load my sprites and then a SceneController to create the game objects. I store the sprite in a dictionary in GameLoader, to get the sprite I want to make a function to receive a specific sprite from the GameLoader. It was working when it was in one Class but now it are two classes I have problems getting the Sprite. I get this error

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
SceneController.createGeometry () (at Assets/Controllers/SceneController.cs:18)
SceneController.Start () (at Assets/Controllers/SceneController.cs:13)
```

**SceneController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Linq; 
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SceneController : MonoBehaviour {
    string[] geometryObjects = { "cube", "cube", "circle", "circle", "cube_small" };
    int objectCount = 5;
    GameLoader gameLoader;

    void Start () {
        createGeometry();
    }

    void createGeometry() {
        foreach (string geometryObject in geometryObjects) {
            Debug.Log(gameLoader.getGeometrySprite(geometryObject));
            GameObject geometryGameObject = new GameObject();
            geometryGameObject.name = geometryObject;
            geometryGameObject.tag = "Geometry";
            geometryGameObject.transform.position = new Vector3(0,0,0);
            geometryGameObject.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = gameLoader.getGeometrySprite(geometryObject);
            geometryGameObject.AddComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); 
            geometryGameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider2D>(); 
        }
    }
}
```

**GameLoader.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameLoader : MonoBehaviour {
    Dictionary<string, Sprite> geometrySprites;

    void Awake () {
        LoadSprites();
    }

    void LoadSprites() {
        geometrySprites = new Dictionary<string, Sprite>();
        Sprite[] geometrySpritesResources = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("Images/Geometry");

        foreach(Sprite geometrySpritesResource in geometrySpritesResources) {
            geometrySprites[geometrySpritesResource.name] = geometrySpritesResource;
        }
    }

    public Sprite getGeometrySprite(string spriteName) {
        return geometrySprites[spriteName];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the code that initializes `gameLoader`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set the `gameLoader` variable before trying to access it. Otherwise its value will always be `null` by default. There are lots of ways to do this. The simpler one is to just search for it in the scene using [`FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html). Just add this to your SceneController's `Awake`:

```
void Awake () 
{
    gameLoader = FindObjectOfType<GameLoader>();
}
```

Remember that `FindObjectOfType` should be used only in one-time operations:

> Please note that this function is very slow. It is not recommended to
>   use this function every frame. In most cases you can use the singleton
>   pattern instead.